# Calculating Running Totals - TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to calculate running totals over a time period with each time period rolling up into the next period for a cumulative total.

There will be multiple events in the real data along with multiple event types and cost types - but in the example below, I'm only showing one event and one type. If I can get this to work, I can make it work for the other types as well.

The screenshot below is my expected output:

[image]

I would like to sum the amounts for each month's number for both types of reserves: Expense & Indemnity - so month 1 would have a total of $31.7k.  Month 2 has a total of approximately $4.1k so that would be added to the prior months' total giving me 35.9k.  And this running total should continue on to the last record.

I am trying various ways to sum through a window function but so far I am unable to get the expected outcome.  Any suggestions on how to achieve this total?

Sample data is found below:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
( Catastrophe VARCHAR (60), Type VARCHAR (256), CostType VARCHAR (256), FirstLossDate DATE, MonthNumber INT, Amount DECIMAL (38, 6) );

INSERT INTO #temptable
( Catastrophe, Type, CostType, FirstLossDate, MonthNumber, Amount) 
VALUES
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Expense - A&O', N'2007-09-13', 1, 13460.320000),
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Indemnity', N'2007-09-13', 1, 18314.610000),
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Expense - A&O', N'2007-09-13', 2, -1589.340000),
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Indemnity', N'2007-09-13', 2, 5750.000000),
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Expense - A&O', N'2007-09-13', 3, -2981.250000),
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Indemnity', N'2007-09-13', 3, -10000.000000),
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Expense - A&O', N'2007-09-13', 4, 0.000000),
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Indemnity', N'2007-09-13', 4, 0.000000),
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Expense - A&O', N'2007-09-13', 5, 0.000000),
('Hurricane Humberto', 'Reserve', 'Indemnity', N'2007-09-13', 5, 0.000000);

SELECT Catastrophe,
       Type,
       CostType,
       FirstLossDate,
       MonthNumber,
       Amount,
       SUM ( Amount ) OVER (PARTITION BY Catastrophe, MonthNumber, Type ORDER BY MonthNumber ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  ) AS RunningTotals,
       SUM ( Amount ) OVER (PARTITION BY Catastrophe, Type, MonthNumber) AS RunningTotal2
FROM #temptable
ORDER BY Catastrophe,
         Type,
         MonthNumber;

DROP TABLE #temptable;
```

Comment: I think you need to be using RANGE rather than ROWS when defining the partition window.
ROWS and RANGE handle ties differently with ROWS adding incrementally in an arbitrary order and RANGE giving the same value to all rows within the range.

Comment: No, SIA2 - RunningTotal2 is not what I'm looking for. It resets on every month and is not cumulative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT Catastrophe,
       Type,
       CostType,
       FirstLossDate,
       MonthNumber,
       Amount,
       SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Catastrophe, Type ORDER BY MonthNumber asc RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS RunningTotals
FROM 
       temptable
ORDER BY 
       Catastrophe,
       Type,
       MonthNumber;
```

I think your main problem was with `partition by` clause - it is meant to "reset" the calculation - so you can calculate windowing function for many groups.

As per documentation:

> PARTITION BY Divides the query result set into partitions. The window
>   function is applied to each partition separately and computation
>   restarts for each partition.

[REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b992/13)

Comment: Swapping ROWS for RANGE gives an exact match to the expected output.

Comment: Thanks! I've never used RANGE between and that does work.  Need to look into that functionality a bit more.  Appreciate it.

Comment: If you need a bit more detail then this might be a good starting point:
https://sqlperformance.com/2019/08/sql-performance/t-sql-bugs-pitfalls-and-best-practices-window-functions

Comment: Difference between using rows and range in here is, that range will take into account also rows with the same element in ordered field (& partition), and rows will literally take rows (i.e. everything what was before + current, once we order it). Partition by is the second important thing - you cannot partition by month, cause this will "reset" calculation always, when you get to new month.